# Capitalization in direct speech without quotation marks

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, colons, indirect-speech

My question has been largely answered in the discussion linked to below. However, one question remains: in mid-sentence hypothetical direct speech without quotation marks, what is preferable capitalization?

People are incensed at the wealth of others: why does he have all that and I do not? they wonder.

or:

People are incensed at the wealth of others: Why does he have all that and I do not? they wonder.

My instinctive preference is for the former, without capitalization of the initial word of the thought. Yet it being a complete thought coming from a hypothetical "wonderer", not from the author, would seem to suggest otherwise.

Many thanks in advance!

[Capitalization with quotation marks](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/189572/capitalization-with-quotation-marks)

Comment: I can also see a second and third dilemma, that you began a new sentence after the question mark *"...I do not? they wonder."* and that the first letter of the new sentence doesn't begin with a capital letter. I would place the verb *wonder* somewhere before the thought being expressed.

Comment: related: [Capitalization After Colon](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6931/capitalization-after-colon)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use quotation marks as follows:

*People are incensed at the wealth of others: "Why does he have all that and I do not?" they wonder.*

Even though you are, in a sense, inventing the quotation I think it's allowable and solves both the problem of the capital and that of the question mark.